# Put decimal points in exam class different than 0.5

Tags: exam

I am using the `exam` class to create exams, but in my country grades usually go from 0 to 10, then sometimes I need point like 0.2, 0.25, 0.75 ... How I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Did you check the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)? So please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: The class doesn't support this; an alternative might be using points multiplied by 100 and maybe printing them divided by 100.